# Can't get Spring Webflux using Kotlin coroutines to return anything in a Flow

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

At https://bitbucket.org/HughG/kotlin_coroutine_play/src/master/spring-coro-server/src/main/kotlin/ I have a simple Spring Boot Webflux app in which I'm trying to return a (Kotlin coroutines) Flow.  I based this loosely on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kotlin-coroutines but, rather than using a repository as my source of data, I have an in-memory `@MessagingGateway` providing a `QueueChannel` of "event" objects (simple Kotlin data class with one String property).  In this toy project the channel is being populated by a method which is `@Scheduled` to run every few seconds.

The behaviour I want is that, when a request is made to get the current list of events

- if there are some events in the channel, remove them all and return them;
- otherwise wait (for some timeout) for the next event and return that
- unless the timeout is exceeded, in which case return an empty list of events.

However, all the variations I've tried have one of the following results.

- Responds with an empty JSON object.
- Doesn't respond at all, because it's an infinite Flow and is actively waiting for every new event.
- Throws a `KotlinNullPointerException` trying to serialise the result (when I use a `channelFlow` inside which I wrap an explicit `async`/`await` pair around requests to the channel.
- Does work, if I explictly collect the `Flow` to a `List`, which requires me to wrap the whole thing with `runBlocking`, thereby defeating the point of using coroutines/webflux, in that the request thread is blocked while waiting for events, rather than being available for re-use.

If anyone has the time to look at the project (which should build as it is, using Gradle), play with the sample endpoints, and give me a clue what I'm missing, I'd be grateful.

EDIT: There's also a separate toy project within the top-level build, called `coroutine-sort`, which you can ignore for the purposes of this question.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I looked at a couple of related questions, but they didn't seem to help.

- [Webflux Kotlin Coroutines Flow doesn't return any results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398548/webflux-kotlin-coroutines-flow-doesnt-return-any-results)
- [Spring Boot Rest Service With Kotlin Coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558802/spring-boot-rest-service-with-kotlin-coroutines)